# Ajax sort using two compounded dropdowns

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, sorting, lazy-loading

Currently, I am using a nav menu to display the categories of items, using Ajax to sort/limit items shown to the chosen category, and using lazyload to display additional items on scroll.

I am wanting to change the nav menu to two button dropdowns – one for categories, and the other for locations. I would like the user to be able to sort by category OR store, independently, or by category AND store, in conjunction.

Scenario:

- User chooses Category A

  - Category A items for ALL locations are shown
- User then chooses Location A

  - Category A items for Location A are shown
- User then chooses Location B

  - Category A items for Location B are shown
- User then chooses Category B
  – Category B items for Location B are shown

I am hoping that this can be usable in reverse order as well, i.e. if the user chooses location first, and *then* category.

I am knee-deep in code - aren't we all! ;) - and think I need another pair of eyes to slap me back straight!  Where am I going wrong?!? TIA for the help.

FYI, currently when I select the category, it works fine. When I then select a location, it just shows that location's items within the last category, regardless of the category previously chosen, and then when I scroll, lazyload begins displaying items from all locations and all categories. If I choose the location first, it shows that location's items from the last category. Any help is much appreciated.

**Here are the buttons:** (include-menu)

```
 <div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Choose Category <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li'; if (!$_REQUEST || $_REQUEST['show']) { echo ' class="active"'; } echo '><a class="pawn-sort" href="?show=all">Show All</a></li>'."\n";
            $result = $site->query("SELECT * FROM CATEGORIES ORDER BY NAME ASC");
            while ($data = $result->fetch_array())
            {
                $category_id = $data['ID'];
                $cats = $site->query("SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE CATEGORIES LIKE '%$category_id%'");
                if ($cat = $cats->fetch_array())
                {
                    echo '<li'; if ($category_id == $_REQUEST['category']) { echo ' class="active"'; } echo '>
                    <a href="?category=' . $category_id . '&kingdom='.$kingdom.'" class="pawn-sort">' . ucwords($data['NAME']) . '</a>
                    <!-- <a data-index="' . $category_id . '" name="cat" href="#">' . ucwords($data['NAME']) . '</a> -->
                    </li>'."\n";
                }
            }
        echo '</ul>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Choose Store <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="?category=all">Show All</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="?category=' . $category_id . '&kingdom=location1" class="pawn-sort">location1</a></li>
            <li><a href="?category=' . $category_id . '&kingdom=location2" class="pawn-sort">location2</a></li>
            <li><a href="?category=' . $category_id . '&kingdom=location3" class="pawn-sort">location3</a></li>
            <li><a href="?category=' . $category_id . '&kingdom=location4" class="pawn-sort">location4</a></li>
            <li><a href="?category=' . $category_id . '&kingdom=location5" class="pawn-sort">location5</a></li>
            <li><a href="?category=' . $category_id . '&kingdom=location6" class="pawn-sort">location6</a></li>
            <li><a href="?category=' . $category_id . '&kingdom=location7" class="pawn-sort">location7</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Here is where ajax gets the items and displays them: (ajax-get-items)

```
define('ITEMS_PER_PAGE',8);

$category = $_GET['category'] ? $_GET['category'] : null;
$kingdom = $_GET['kingdom'] ? $_GET['kingdom'] : null;
if ($kingdom)
{
    $this_store = " AND STORE = '$kingdom'";
} else {
$this_store = '';
}
$page = $_GET['page'] ? ($_GET['page']) : 1;

if($page < 1)
{
$page = 1;
}

$first = $_GET['first'] ? ($_GET['first']) : 0;


$next = $page + 1;
$start = ($page - 1 ) * ITEMS_PER_PAGE;
$offset =  ITEMS_PER_PAGE;



if ($category) {
$que = "SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE QUANTITY != '0' AND STATUS = '1' AND CATEGORIES LIKE '%$category%' $this_store ORDER BY DATE DESC LIMIT $start, $offset";
$queAll = "SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE QUANTITY != '0' AND STATUS = '1' AND CATEGORIES LIKE '%$category%' $this_store ORDER BY DATE DESC";
} else {
$que = "SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE QUANTITY != '0' AND STATUS = '1' $this_store ORDER BY DATE DESC LIMIT $start, $offset";
$queAll = "SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE QUANTITY != '0' AND STATUS = '1' $this_store ORDER BY DATE DESC";
    }




// COUNT HOW MANY ITEMS AVAILABLE
$resultsAll = $site->query("$queAll");
$countAll = count($resultsAll->fetch_assoc());

// MAIN QUERY
$results = $site->query("$que");

$output = "";
$counter = 0;

while ($cupon = $results->fetch_array()) {

$name = $cupon['NAME'];
$price = $cupon['PRICE'];
$store = $cupon['STORE'];
$sku = $cupon['SKU'];
$upc = $cupon['UPC'];
$img_id = $cupon['IMAGE_ID'];
$notify = $cupon['NOTIFY'];
$store_sku = $cupon['STORE_SKU'];
$out = "&out=true";
$img = "img/l/{$img_id}_1.jpg";

$output .= '<div class="pin">
<div id="pin_' . $counter . '">
<div class="thumbnail" style="overflow: hidden;">
<ul class="img-list">
<li>
<a href="/buy.php?sku=' . $sku . '">
<img class="radius" src="/' . $img . '">
<span class="text-content"><span>View Product Info</span></span></a>
</li>
</ul>
<div class="caption pinkish" style="margin-top:-9px;">
<h4 class="pin-title">' . $name . '</h4>
<hr style="margin-bottom:5px;">' . "\n";

$kingdoms = $castle->query("SELECT NAME, CITY, STATE FROM KINGDOMS WHERE ID = '$store' LIMIT 1");
$kingdom = $kingdoms->fetch_array();

$output .= '<a href="/buy.php?sku=' . $sku . '" class="pin-location pull-right" style="padding-top:3px;">#' . $store_sku . '</a>
<a href="http://privatepawns.com/kingdom/' . $store . '/" target="_blank" class="pin-location"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span> ' . $kingdom['CITY'] . '</a>
<hr style="margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:3px;">
<p class="pin-price">
<a href="/buy.php?sku=' . $sku . '" class="btn btn-info btn-sm pull-right btn-green" style="margin-top:3px;" role="button">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search small"></span> More info
</a>
<span class="price">$' . number_format($price, 2) . '</span>

<div class="clearfix"></div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>' . "\n";

$counter++;
}


$output.= '<script type="text/javascript">
var container = document.querySelector(\'#container\');
var msnry;
// initialize Masonry after all images have loaded
imagesLoaded( container, function() {
    msnry = new Masonry( container, {
    // options
    itemSelector: \'.pin\'
    });
});
</script>';


if($category)
{

if(((($page -1) * ITEMS_PER_PAGE + $counter)< $countAll) )
{

    $output.= '<div id="page-nav"><a  href="ajax-pagination/'.$next.'/'.$category.'"></a></div>';

} else {
    $output.= "<script>$('#container').infinitescroll('unbind', {debug: true});</script>";
}


} else {

if(((($page -1) * ITEMS_PER_PAGE + $counter)< $countAll) )
{
    $output.= '<div id="page-nav"><a  href="ajax-pagination/'.$next.'"></a></div>';

} else {
    $output.= "<script>$('#container').infinitescroll('unbind', {debug: true});</script>";
}

}


echo $output;
```

Here is the jquery:

```
<script>
    $('.filter').on('click',function(){
        var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $('#alist').isotope({filter: filterValue});
    })


    var $container = $('#container');

    function customMasonry(newElements)
    {

        // hide new items while they are loading
        var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
        // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
        $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
            // show elems now they're ready
            $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
            var msnry;
            // initialize Masonry after all images have loaded
            imagesLoaded( $container, function() {
                msnry = new Masonry( container, {
                    // options
                    itemSelector: '.pin'
                });
            });
        });
    }


    function customScroll()
    {
        $container.infinitescroll({
                navSelector  : '#page-nav',    // selector for the paged navigation
                debug: false,
                animate      : false,
                errorCallback : function() {
                    $container.infinitescroll('destroy');
                    $.removeData(this);
                },
                nextSelector : '#page-nav:first a:first',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
                itemSelector : '.pin',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
                loading: {
                    finishedMsg: '',
                    img: 'loading.gif',
                    msgText: ''
                }
            },
            // trigger Masonry as a callback
            function( newElements ) {
                customMasonry(newElements)
            }
        );
    }


    $(function(){



        var isMobile = window.matchMedia("only screen and (min-width: 760px)");

        if (isMobile.matches) {
            $("#categories").sticky({topSpacing: 70});
        }


        customScroll();


        $('.pawn-sort').click(function(event){

            $('#container').html('');
            $('#container').infinitescroll('bind');

            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#container").offset().top -369
            }, 0);


            $url = $(this).attr('href');

            var res = $url.split("&");

            var cat = res[0].split("=");
            var $category = cat[1];

            var king = res[1].split("=");
            var $kingdom = king[1];

            if($category == 'all' )
            {
                $category = null;
            }

            if($kingdom == 'all' )
            {
                $kingdom = null;
            }

            $('#container').css({height:500});

            $.ajax({
                method: "GET",
                url: "ajax-get-items.php",
                data: { page: "1", category: $category, kingdom: $kingdom, first: true }
            })
                .done(function( msg ) {

                      $('#container').html("<div id='gif'><img src='loading.gif'/></div>");

                    setTimeout(
                        function()
                        {
                            $('#container').html(msg);

                            // Reset the plugin before intializing it again
                            $('#container').infinitescroll('destroy');
                            $('#container').data('infinitescroll', null);

                            // Initialize plugin
                            $('#container').infinitescroll(
                                {
                                    state: {
                                        isDestroyed: false,
                                        isDone: false,
                                        isDuringAjax : false
                                    }
                                }
                            );

                            customScroll();

                        }, 500);

                });
            event.preventDefault();
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please add the problem description above to your question (and not in a comment).

Comment: Problem description added to question.